# What is the best way to access/share object instances among different classes in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar application with 3 tab bar items. Each of them is linked to a different view controller class.

How can I use/change the content of an object instance of class A in class B?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: define your model, share it between your VC's.

Long Answer: Watch "Session 116 - Model-View-Controller for iPhone OS" talk from WWDC 2010 for a wealth of information that will help you understand what you should be doing.

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: +1 for correct answer, would have given +2 for not recommending sharing via App-Delegate if that was possible.